# GameMaker: Studio Infinite terrain / endless jumper

Tags: algorithm, logic, game-maker

I want to make a little "Doodle Jump" game to get more experience with GM:S.
My only problem is the infinite terrain/blocks/room algorithm in GM. Can somebody explain how this works? Or an example with obj_block , obj_player?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure to what you are referring to with "infinite terrain/blocks/room algorithm in GM". However a doodle jump style game is quite simple, make the player not move vertically and instead move all blocks down. Then, when a block is out the bottom of the room move it to just above the top of the screen with a random x position.

```
///Player movement code///

//update horizontal
x += horizontal_speed

//move all blocks down
with (obj_block) {
  y -= other.vertical_speed
}


///in block step event///

//check if out of screen
if (y+(sprite_height) > room_height) {
  y = -sprite_height
  x = random_range(0, room_width - sprite_width)
}
```

might need a little bit of padding on edges but thats dependent on your game, good luck!